# How to model a rotated cardioid with mesh density relative to surface tangent?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, differential-geometry, surfaces

Cardioids $r=1-\sin(\theta)$ are simple. Creating a surface by rotating one about its omphalos, less simple. Creating a mesh which indicates the tangent of the surface relative to this axis is far beyond my present scope.

Even on Wolfram the surfaces they show which are supposed to be this shape (does it have a name?) visibly have a strange flatness around the equator which looks incorrect.

Pointers?

My intention is modeling the gravitational curve of visible universe. The outward curved surface pole representing deep voids with least curve. The navel/omphalos representing event horizon with most extreme curve.  Ideally a mesh indicative of surface tangent would then be applied.

Thank you.

Comment: I add some tags seemingly related tags to your post. Please remove if anything is unnecessary.

Comment: Could you post a sketch of what you are trying to do? I have developed a method for bodies of revolution about arbitrary planiforms, but I don't know if that is what you are after.

Comment: Here is a link to the project "3d cardioid with mesh".

Comment: Thank you both for helping or even trying to.  :)

Comment: I have created geometrically perfect 3D structure of rotated cardioid but it was done using a curved path method and thus the surface mesh is not relative to surface curve deviation from a sphere which is what I’m trying to create.  
Curve((p+sin(theta),n theta, theta),theta,zero,x pi)  p gives the internal perforation 0=sphere 1=classical cardioid. n gives curve ratio. When n=0 there is a simple form at n=4.3 there is an anharmonic relationship and the fuller form is visible.  x determines rotations and so at higher values (given n being anharmonic) x gives more dense surface mesh.